# Hosting NAS, a sql database, and streaming to chromecast all over a home network

Tags: media-server, sqlite, chromecast

First of all sorry if this isn't the right type of question for here, but I didn't know where else to ask.

I have raspberry pi that I've worked with before (although not that extensively) but I'll soon be moving to a different setup and I was wondering how to implement a variety of requirements.

What I want is somewhat of a hybrid between Raspbian and Raspbmc. Here's a bit of an outline of what I'm looking for.

I have a hard drive with a bunch of music and movies. I want this to be hosted on my local network, but also be able to have videos streamed to a chromecast ( I was looking at a guide [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=73464&p=528057) ) and music streamed to bluetooth speakers. It would optimal if this could be done with a nice user interface.

Also, I would like to be able have a small sql database on the rpi that I can manage and access remotely.

I understand this is kinda of a lot, and I'm hoping it's all possible with one device and OS. Please let me know of your suggestions, guides, advice, or if I should take my post somewhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Raspbmc is just Raspbian and kodi, it's already setup up for NAS and SQL, all you have to do is setup the bluetooth.